# Iterator inside Iterator ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, iterator, concurrentmodification

I am having the following problem:

Given an ArrayList (let's call it list), how can I "double-iterate" through it without getting  ConcurrentModificationException?

Here's what I've tried:

```
iterator out = list.iterator();
iterator in;
while(out.hasNext()){
    ...
    in = list.iterator();
    while(in.hasNext()){
        ...
        if(something)
             in.remove();
    }
```

Comment: what is it?????

Comment: it is in, sorry I've typed in a hurry

Comment: You cannot use two iterators of the same list and remove an element with one iterator while the other iterator is still busy iterating over that collection.

Comment: And why would you do that? Could you explain what you are aiming to achieve through this double iterating approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. A potential solution might be to mark objects to be removed, for example:

```
final List<Foo> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

for (Foo a : list)
{
    for (Foo b : list)
    {
        if (something)
        {
            toRemove.add(b);
        }
    }
}
list.removeAll(toRemove);
```

You may need some additional checks to see that the object isn't already marked for removal. It's impossible to say given how vague your example is.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to modify an iterator. It will give you concurrentModification exception.

In java 8 you can easily remove it using
`list.removeIf(someCondition)`

Try this link [java8 collections](http://www.concretepage.com/java/jdk-8/java-8-list-example-with-foreach-removeif-replaceall-and-sort)

Answer (score 1):

The `Iterator` instance provided through a call to `List#iterator` method preserves a *count* scalar allowing to detect external changes to the `Collection` container.

When an element is removed from the collection by any other mean than going through the same `Iterator#remove(T)` call, the *count* is not updated behind the scenes.
Therefore when you request for the `#next()` element through the iterator instance, the *count* is checked against an *expected value* and if both values does not match (since an element has been removed through another iterator) a `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown (*even though you may be working in a single threaded environment*).

The solution whould be, as @Michael stated, to keep track of the container elements that should be removed then perform a bulk delete:

```java
Collection<Object> temp = new ArrayList<>();
iterator out = list.iterator();
iterator in;
while (out.hasNext()) {
    // ...
    in = list.iterator();
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        // ...
        if(something)
             // just mark the element for deletion
             temp.add(in.next());
    }
}

// delete all the obsolete elements
list.removeAll(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

In collection once iterator creator If you try to modify the content not through same iterator it will throw concurrent exception.If you required some special kind of iterator then you can go ahead and implement your own.

Comment: In this case, it will throw Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException    and not the concurrent modification exception. I am looking out the reason behind it.